# Angularjs memory leak on page reload in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, memory-leaks

A single page applcation based on Foundation for apps basically works fine across browsers. The only exception is: reloading the whole page in **Internet Explorer**. Doing so causes memory usage of IE to grow, on each reload. Chrome and Firefox do not do this.

Though this is not the usual behavior, it affects me during development when the page gets reloaded often to load code changes. At some point IE crashes. Although users don't reload and are not affected it leaves a bad taste that this happens at all.

Why in IE but not the other browsers?

How to solve this?

Foundation for apps is build on angularJS and I suspect my issue is created somewhere in there.

But navigating the sections within the app through "ui-router" seems fine, I do not see increase in memory usage there. So I think that the directives, services etc. seem fine.

Comment: Too broad of a question; not enough specifics. You might want to dig more into this and present the info, so SO users can help. Simple search revealed this resource: [Diagnosing memory problems in your webpages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255003(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was afraid of that. But thanks for diggung up that link, looks helpful!

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have a similar problem with IE in a Knockout based application.